# Use Azure Maps search to get a list of addresses on street

Tags: azure-maps

Is it possible to use Azure Maps Search Api to get a list of addresses with house numbers just supplying street and locality / postal code?

Just passing the street and postal code only gives me information about that street and cross streets.

Comment: Check this Document if helps: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-maps/how-to-search-for-address.md

Answer (score 0):

Most geocoding services will not return a list of house numbers that are on a given street. The reason for this is that geocoders typically approximate the location of street numbers along a street based on the block number range. This means that geocoders will approximate the location of any street number, even if they don't exist.

A database of every known street number for every street is generally not available/used in geocoders at scale for a number of reasons;

- Databases of this accuracy are only available for some cities/countries, and quickly become outdated. This level of accuracy isn't available globally.
- Searching a massive database of street addresses would be much slower than approximating the location of an address based on the block address range of a road.

If you only need this for a smaller area (like a single city), you can check to see if that city has a GIS department who make parcel data openly available. If they do, then you could build a simple search service based on top of that data that would be able to achieve what you are looking for.